# Why does justify-content: center fail when I narrow the viewport-width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On a wide-enough viewport the content of the 'flex-container' element - 'George Zuberi' - stays horizontally-centred thanks to `justify-content: center;`. However when you narrow the viewport a lot it fails. It needs `text-align: center;` to still stay horizontally-centred. Why is this?

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: #ECF0DE;
}

.flex-container {
    /* text-align: center; */
    color: #BD6EB6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
  
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
       George Zuberi
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: The text is indeed centered in the first column of your 3 columns grid. Where did you expect it to be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the contents of the flex container with any html element, for example, `span`, then you will easily understand what's happening here.

Contents of the flex container are actually centered within the flex container but when screen is small enough that the text `George Zuberi` cannot fit in one line, it wraps and that's when it seems that the contents of the flex container are not centered.

As you can see in the example below, `justify-content: center` applies on the `span` element (yellow color) which is why it is centered within the flex container (red color) but text inside the `span` element isn't centered.

If you want the text inside the `span` element to also be centered, then add `text-align: center` on `span` element.

You can use `justify-content` to center anything within a flex container and your text is indeed centered within `flex-container`. Add background color to `flex-container` to understand things better.

As a tip, instead of writing text directly within the `flex-container`, wrap the text within any html element.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #ECF0DE;
}

.flex-container {
  background: red;
  color: #BD6EB6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <span>George Zuberi</span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yousaf I've definitely found a solution. I guess what I take away from this: i) try not to use `justify-content` to center text and ii) if you are doing that, it won't be effective when that text wraps onto more than 1 line?

Comment: @tonitone103 you can use `justifty-content` to center anything within a flex container

Comment: There is definitely *no need for a span*. `justify-content: center` will also (horzontally, i.e. along the flex axis) center plain text inside it, treating it as flex items, regardless if in on line or wrapped in several line if width is not wide enough to fit it in one line. The span even prevents the centering if you apply a `width` setting to it as you did. Unless you use `text-align: center` on it, which again makes it superfluous. Just forget the `span`.

Comment: @Johannes i never said that there is a need for a span element around the text. I wanted OP to visualize that the `justify-content` will indeed horizontally center anything inside the flex-container and it only seems to the OP that text isn't centered when it wraps. OP wants the text to be centered even when it wraps, `text-align` is what really needed here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason lies in the `.grid-container`: You have to limit it to one column (which will then fill the parent and which will also cause the flex-container to be full width, in which again the centering will work as expected:

Addition after some comments: The contents of the flex-container *are*  centered insinde the flex-container as desired. The reason why the text isn't appearing in the middle of the page or of the outer container is that the outer container consists of three grid-columns, which are *not* apparently visible in this example.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    background-color: #ECF0DE;
}

.flex-container {
    /* text-align: center; */
    color: #BD6EB6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
  
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
       George Zuberi
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: OP wants to center the contents of the `flex-container`, not center `flex-container` within the `grid-container`

Comment: the contents of the flex-container *are*  centered, it's just that the flex-container isn't in the middle.

Comment: @Yousaf His grid has 3 columns, the flex-container is in the first colum and the content is centered inside the flex-container.

Comment: Why would you use a grid with 1 column and 1 row? Isn't that just a div? You could just have `height: 100%` on the `.flex-container` instead I guess. Maybe OP wants to achieve something else than he is actually asking.

Comment: I don't know why. I just gave the answer why the text content isn't centered (on the page / in the outer container), and that inside the flex-container it's centered anyway.

Comment: @XCS _Why would you use a grid with 1 column and 1 row?_ maybe OP posted only that code which is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Yousaf please read my previous comment (and the addition to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i'm right because i never use grid so i could be wrong, but from what i can see is that you create 3 rows in the grid by using 1fr 1fr 1fr wich means give every row 33% room. in your 33% room you say center my text. so when you reduce your screen-size your 33% percent gets cropped up and automatically goes more to the left, but because you said it has to be centered in that 33% space it moves with the space when it gets reduced to stay centered at the middle, does this make sense?